# How to configure gsutil?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I followed the [Google instructions](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/gsutil_install.html#authenticate) to set up gsutil. It states that after runnig 'gsutil config' in terminal I should see:

> This script will create a boto config file at /.boto
>   containing your credentials, based on your responses to the following
>   questions.
>
> Please navigate your browser to the following URL:
>   <`http://urlto/authorization/dialog`> In your browser you should see a
>   page that requests you to authorize gsutil to access Google Cloud
>   Storage on your behalf. After you approve, an authorization code will
>   be displayed.
>
> Enter the authorization code:

however I get this response instead:

```
root@myserver# gsutil config
No command was given.

Choose one of -b, -d, -e, or -r to do something.
Try `/usr/bin/gsutil --help' for more information.
```

I am using gsutil version 3 on Ubuntu, and trying suggested flags with /usr/bin/gsutil does not give any sensible result.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Pretty sure you have the "configure and manage GrandStream BudgeTone 100 VOIP and GS2000 phones" package installed, which is also called gsutil.  So that is likely causing the issue.  If you don't need the BudgeTone tools then remove them.  Or, explicitly invoke the google tools by using the full path to your home directory where gstools was untarred/unzipped.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gsutil  
sudo easy_install -U pip  
sudo pip2 install gsutil  
gsutil ls gs://uspto-pair/applications/0800401*   
gsutil -config
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you try to install gsutil using `apt install gsutil` which installs "GrandStream" manager instead of Google's gsutil.

First, you need to uninstall the wrong package:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gsutil
```

Then, you can install gsutil according to the [installation guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install).

Here is how you can do it in **Ubuntu**:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli
```